# "Unable to connect to Upstart" error when installing git-all

Tags: dpkg, upstart, git

I am using 15.04.

So I'm working with git and I installed the standard version. I set up the ssh keys and was able to clone one of my repositories to the correct folder. Everything was working great and then I decided it was a good idea to install more packages. I ran `sudo apt-get install git-all`. I'm looking at error codes now having to deal with upstart.

```
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is what happens when I even update/upgrade my system. At this point all I'm looking to do is be able to install software and update my current software. Is there any way I can potentially reverse this issue or at least correct it?

Edit: Thankfully this issue was solved only a day or two after it happened. The accepted answer worked perfectly and took care of my issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to forcibly remove `runit`. Running `sudo dpkg -r runit` should work. You might need to use one of the `--force-*` options.

Comment: `git-daemon-run` depended on `runit` so I removed it, then removed `runit`. Now testing to see if git still works. That did however fix my current issue!

Comment: `git-daemon-run` is probably for running a GIt server (as in having `git://` links to your computer for remote access). I don't have `runit` installed and can use git.

Comment: I had to do a`sudo apt-get remove --purge git-daemon-run` after all that to stop all the 'unmet dependency' errors.

Answer (score 22):

It's happening because of this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1448164

You need to remove `runit` and `git-daemon-run`. That should fix the problem.

```
sudo apt-get purge runit git-daemon-run
```

Don't forget to visit the bug report and clicking **Yes, this bug affects me**.

#### `git-all` without error

It seems you can have `git-all` with daemon support without failing on this error. `git-all` recommends either `git-daemon-run` or `git-daemon-sysvinit` package. `apt` was choosing `git-daemon-run` as first choice. But If you explicitly mention the package you want (i.e `git-daemon-sysvinit`), `apt` won't try to install `git-daemon-run`.

All you need to do is

```
sudo apt-get install git-all git-daemon-sysvinit
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You are right, thank you for the **bug** link.

Comment: I got the bug link from [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/796682/61218) and the link to that answer from [Zanna's comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/820065/installing-git-all-causing-problem-on-16-04-1#comment1243584_820065) below the question. Thanks to them. @BillalBEGUERADJ

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt --purge remove git 
sudo apt install git
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling `git-all`, installing `git-daemon-sysvinit`, then installing `git-all` again. If you look at the package properties in Synaptic, you will find that `git-all` depends on **either** `git-daemon-run` **or** `git-daemon-sysvinit`. `git-daemon-run` is the one that gets installed by default for some reason, even though it's broken in Ubuntu 15.04 and up. (See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1448164) But if you install `git-daemon-sysvinit` manually first, then `git-all`'s dependency will be satisfied, by a package that actually works. You can then install `git-all`, and everything should be fine.

Comment: I should have clarified that I was using a workstation and not trying to configure a git server at the time. But for anyone who runs across this and is, this is good info ^

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Ubuntu under a virtual host. If so, you will need to modify initctl to return true using the following steps. First, you need to tell dpkg, that you are going to change the upstart package installation using:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
```

Then, you need to create a dummy initctl as a link to true:

```
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

Comment: I was not using a virtual host but thank you anyway