# Difference between installing git vs installing git-all

Tags: git, version-control

What's the difference between

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```

vs

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Is there any advantage of installing either or all?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Git-all contains all sub-packages, whilst Git only includes main components with minimal dependencies.

As stated in [Git on Debian Packages](https://packages.debian.org/sid/git), Git does for example not include

> graphical user interface and revision tree visualizer, tools for interoperating with other VCS's, or a web interface..

Those are additional packages.

If you look at [Git-all on Debian Packages](https://packages.debian.org/sid/git-all), you see it states

> all sub-packages

Comment: mattias  Any notable advantages of having either or all?

Comment: It totally depends on your requirements =) If you don't need a GUI and you're conservative when it comes to disk usage (however, I don't think the `git-all` is that massive in storage consumption), stick with the `git` package.

Comment: You can even install `git git-gui gitk`, thus including a GUI, but still avoid (1) the email extension for sending patches, (2) SVN support, (3) CVS support, (4) MediaWiki remote support, (5) the web interface via Apache (!) and other things.

Answer (score 13):

On my Ubuntu 17.10 x64 git-all v2.14.1 depends on:

- **git (actually git, 28.7 MiB without dependencies)**
- git-doc (git documentation, 10.8 MiB without dependencies)
- git-cvs (git-cvs interoperability, 1.1 MiB without dependencies)
- git-mediawiki (MediaWiki remote helper, 0.8 MiB without dependencies)
- git-svn (git-svn interoperability, 1.0 MiB without dependencies)
- git-email (git email add-on, 0.8 MiB without dependencies)
- git-gui (git GUI, 2.2 MiB without dependencies)
- gitk (git revision tree visualizer, 1.5 MiB without dependencies)
- gitweb (git web interface, 0.8 MiB without dependencies)
- git-el (git emacs support, in my case 113 MiB *with all dependencies*)

In my case git-all installed 93 packages totalling 215 MiB **with all dependencies**.

**So, it's up to you which packages to install..**

P.S. You can get all this information, for example, from Synaptic Package Manager.

Answer (score 10):

I believe running `sudo apt-get install git-all` is roughly equivalent to running `sudo apt-get --install-suggests install git`. The latter caused problems for me on Ubuntu 15.10. Among other packages, it tried to install git-daemon-run, which didn't work. (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1448164)

Installing `git-daemon-sysvinit` first, then `git`, worked better for me. `git-daemon-sysvinit` replaces `git-daemon-run`.

So, to finish my thought, you can install either `git-all` or just `git`, depending on your requirements. But `git-all` has the caveat that you will need to install another package first. (git-daemon-sysvinit)

Comment: @Anwar, Is there a place to download git compiled binaries and just extract them? No installation or compilation. Just download it as you download ant other binary TAR.

Comment: @Royi I haven't done such installation but I think it should be possible. For example, check this https://git-annex.branchable.com/install/Linux_standalone/

Comment: @Anwar, What does it mean Git Annex?