# "Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart" error when installing git-all

Tags: dpkg, git

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1.

I try to install git:

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```

I got this error:

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to fix it?