# Error in installing any program through terminal

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm unable to install any program through terminal. Whenever I write any command to install something it always returns this error

[image: I took the screenshot of the Terminal and it always shows this error.]

Comment: You don't need to add screenshot, you can dump output by putting `>` key in front of it

Comment: Please do not post terminal screenshots. Copy/past the entire error messages instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vivid - failed to connect to upstart: connection refused](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614970/vivid-failed-to-connect-to-upstart-connection-refused)

Comment: See also [Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused: Errors were encountered while processing: runit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654951/failed-to-connect-to-socket-com-ubuntu-upstart-connection-refused-errors-were)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to connect to Upstart" error when installing git-all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631615/unable-to-connect-to-upstart-error-when-installing-git-all)